# How do I change the background color from items in array with same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Here I display characters in table**
js

```
function Init()
{
    debugger;
    //start page
    const text = potterCharacters.map(character => {
        const { name, actor, image } = character
        return `<tr>
            <td id="column" class="column">${name}</td>
            <td id="column" class="column">${actor}</td>
            <td id="column" class="column"><img src="${image}"/></td>
        </tr>`
    })
    document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = text ;
}
```

**Now I want all characters with the same "house" to have the same background color using a function**

*Array, just one character so you understand*

```
let potterCharacters = [
{
  name: "Harry Potter",
  species: "human",
  gender: "male",
  house: "Gryffindor",
  dateOfBirth: "31-07-1980",
  yearOfBirth: 1980,
  ancestry: "half-blood",
  eyeColour: "green",
  hairColour: "black",
  patronus: "stag",
  hogwartsStudent: true,
  hogwartsStaff: false,
  actor: "Daniel Radcliffe",
  alive: true,
  image: "http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/harry.jpg"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add background color to your data and use it in the map function.

```
function Init()
{
    debugger;
    //start page
    const text = potterCharacters.map(character => {
        const { name, actor, image, houseBgColor } = character
        return `<tr class="row" style="background-color: ${houseBgColor}">
            <td class="column">${name}</td>
            <td class="column">${actor}</td>
            <td class="column"><img src="${image}"/></td>
        </tr>`
    })
    document.getElementById("rows").innerHTML = text ;
}
```

If you don't want to or can't modify your data, then you can create a seperate array and get the background color from the colors array.

Example:

```
const colors = {house1: "orange", house2: "blue", house3: "gray"}
```

You can then use it inside the map function as follows (where house is the key in the object which should match your data):

```
<tr class="row" style="background-color: ${colors[house]}">
```

Comment: Thank you tis could work, but the data file is very big and this would take alot of time to add, is there no way to put it in a function thats maybe loops over the array and gets all houses with name "Gryffindor"?

Comment: @OfficialRules then you can use my second suggestion. You need to map houses to colors in that object

Comment: Oh I didnt see that part will try I now

Comment: I'm happy to help